# Unable to send or stream live audio from system input over the internet with C# in windows form

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, file, audio-streaming

I want to develop an online streaming or radio app like https://mixlr.com
I wish to use C#, any framework is fine, ASP.NET MVC, Windows Forms, anything... I would like to stream the audio from a web app. The app will stream my laptop microphone or any input device to the internet.

I don't know how to go about this, where to start or which plugin to use, I've been searching for over a month now but still don't have a breakthrough yet.

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: you need a stream server, together with the iis. The asp.net will be the user interface not the actually streaming program

Comment: How do I go about this, I don't know where to start.